# How to animate button\view from within another buttons ontouch ImageButton view?

Tags: android, button, multi-touch, touch-event, motionevent

See http://www.passsy.de/multitouch-for-all-views/#comment-47486 of which the most relevant code appears below.

If one "TestButton" which extends button is pressed, that view is passed to my "TestButton" code and I can animate that button/view. But I want to animate another view as well. How can I animate a different view from with the view I am creating here or how can I notify my activity to DO ACTION? 
This works on button touched:

```
startAnimation(animationstd);
```

but on another button:

```
useiv.startAnimation(animationstd);
```

causes a null pointer exception.

CODE:

```
package de.passsy.multitouch;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestButton extends Button {

public TestButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            final Animation animationstd = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
            R.anim.fromleft);
    useiv = (TestButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); 
    useiv.startAnimation(animationstd); //this line = null pointer exception
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `findViewById` from inside `TestButton` since you haven't passed to it a reference to the layout your button is located in. You must call `findViewById()` outside the `TestButton` class to find the button that must be animated and then pass that reference to it. Like this:

```
public class TestButton extends Button {

    TestButton mImageButton; // You were calling it useiv

    public TestButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public setAnotherButtonToAnimate(TestButton button) {
        this.mImageButton = button;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            final Animation animationstd = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fromleft);
            if (mImageButton != null) {
                mImageButton.startAnimation(animationstd);
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Then in your `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TestButton imageButton1 = (TestButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    (...)
    btn4 = (TestButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn4.setAnotherButtonToAnimate(imageButton1);
    btn4.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Can I send an array of views through to the view then pick the one I want within the view? I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: This allows me two views, tested and it works. Thank you. I will try passing an array tomorrow. Thank you.